# How to manipulate the input of dates in bash?

Tags: bash, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have to create a shellscript that calculates the difference in days between two dates. The two date inputs need to be in the format DD/MM/YYYY but currently, bash keeps accepting the inputs as the format MM/DD/YYYY. This obviously makes the calculation incorrect but I'm unsure how to configure the two inputs to become usable. Is there any command that can just switch the DD and MM category (something that would swap position 1 and 2 when separated by a forward slash) for just the two input dates?

Here's my shellscript to aid in any advice you might be able to give me.

```
date1=$1
date2=$2
diff1=$(date -d $date1 +%s)
diff2=$(date -d $date2 +%s)
diff="$(($diff2-$diff1))"
days="$(($diff/86400))"
if [ "$days" -lt "0" ]; then
   days="$(($days*-1))"
fi
echo $days
```

For instance:

```
brandon@brandon:~$ ./between 01/04/2020 01/07/2020
3
```

When it should be 91.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

With awk you can do

```
awk -F"/" '{print $2"/"$1"/"$3}'
```

-F is for field separator, given a string in X/Y/Z format the above line will print Y/X/Z

This would be your script

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

date1=$(echo "$1" | awk -F"/" '{print $2"/"$1"/"$3}')
date2=$(echo "$2" | awk -F"/" '{print $2"/"$1"/"$3}')

diff1=$(date -d $date1 +%s)
diff2=$(date -d $date2 +%s)

diff="$(($diff2-$diff1))"
days="$(($diff/86400))"

if [ "$days" -lt "0" ]; then
   days="$(($days*-1))"
fi

echo $days

exit 0
```

Comment: make sure you quote the variables in `echo "$1"` and `echo "$2"` -- you never know what the user will provide you.